# How do I get checked boxes in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question getting checked boxes in asp.net mvc controller...
I have a form that contains many checkboxes with values.. So the user can check as many boxes he wants, and what I need is those values from the checked boxes... What I tried is getting

```
public ActionResult actionName(FormCollection form){...}
```

I do not even know how to access the checkbox value that is being passed into the function...

I have been looking for answer but could not find one.. How do I get it in the controller... I am using C# by the way.

-- edit

I have list of data and pass it into the view... Then, I create the checkbox as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCart" value="@ValueForBox" />
```

where @ValueForBox is the value that I need to obtain in the controller if it is checked..

Comment: Show how you create the checkboxes in the view.

Comment: Also show how you plan to post the form to the controller

Comment: If you using `FormCollection` (which you should not be) then `var value = form["CheckedCart"] will contain the value is the checkbox is checked. What you should be using is a model and binding to your model

Answer (score 0):

** I did not realize it was an old post while answering. But, it may help.

I assume you have have `multiple checkboxes in the View with same name`.
and you need values of the `selected checkboxes` in controller on `form submit`.

if yes, then below will help you.

in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<string> CheckedCart)
    {

    }
```

and in view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCart" value="value1" />

<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCart" value="value2" />

<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedCart" value="whatever the value" />

<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
}
```

When form is submitted. You will get the values of selected checkboxes in parameter `List<string> CheckedCart` in index method. and values for checkboxes which are not selected will be false.

so, as per above example 
`if second checkbox is checked and other are false`.
in the `List<string> CheckedCart` you will get

```
[0] false

[1] value2

[2] false
```